# How to rename a folder with dotnet custom templates?

Tags: .net, templates

I am trying to make a template which can generate the basic template structure.

This is my code:

.template.config/template.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
    "author": "Author",
    "classifications": [ "Templating" ],
    "identity": "Company.Templates.TemplateFile.Json",
    "name": "dotnet new template structure",
    "shortName": "dotnet-template",
    "tags": {
        "type": "item"
    },
    "forms": {
        "folderName" : {
            "identifier": "replace",
            "pattern": "MyTemplate",
            "replacement": ".template.config"
        } 
    },
    "symbols": {
        "author": {
            "type": "parameter",
            "description": "Author of the template",
            "isRequired": true,
            "replaces": "MyAuthor"
        },
        "folderRename": {
            "type": "derived",
            "valueSource": "name",
            "valueTransform": "folderName",
            "replaces": "MyTemplate"
        } 
    }
}
```

MyTemplate/template.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
    "author": "MyAuthor",
    "classifications": [ "C#" ],
    "identity": "Some.Unique.Id",
    "name": "Display name for dotnet new",
    "shortName": "cliname",
    "tags": {
        "language": "C#",
        "type": "project"
    }
}
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

In order to prevent `dotnet pack` from adding the `MyTemplate/template.json`, which is subject of the template, i cannot put it inside a folder named ".template.config"

What i am struggeling with here is finding a way which properly rewrites the "MyTemplate" folder to a ".template.config" folder.

### Update:

This symbol works BUT it can be changed since it is a parameter which i do not want to be possible

```
    "folderRename": {
        "type": "parameter",
        "fileRename": "MyTemplate",
        "defaultValue": ".template.config"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`sources` property](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Reference-for-template.json#source-definition) of `.template.config/template.json` for renaming files.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
    "author": "Author",
    "classifications": [ "Templating" ],
    "identity": "Company.Templates.TemplateFile.Json",
    "name": "dotnet new template structure",
    "shortName": "dotnet-template",
    "tags": {
        "type": "item"
    },
    "symbols": {
        "author": {
            "type": "parameter",
            "description": "Author of the template",
            "isRequired": true,
            "replaces": "MyAuthor"
        },
    },
    "sources": [{
        "rename": {
            "MyTemplate": ".template.config"
        }]
    }
}
```

The other caveat of the OP method is that the "MyTemplate" will be replaced in any other file names and contents as well.